# useWallet() sometimes return null account value in it's object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, web3js

Code which I implemented to my react app for getting metamask info

```
<UseWalletProvider
                    chainId={NETWORK === 'mainnet' ? 1 : 4}
                    connectors={{
                    ...
</UseWalletProvider>
...

const wallet = useWallet()
```

wallet sometimes returns null account value in it's object like below.

```
account: null
balance: "-1"
chainId: 4
connect: ƒ (t)
connector: "injected"
connectors: {fortmatic: Array(2), frame: Array(2), injected: Array(2), portis: Array(2), provided: Array(2), …}
error: null
ethereum: undefined
getBlockNumber: ƒ ()
networkName: "Rinkeby"
reset: ƒ ()
status: "connected"
type: null
...
```

With above issue, it's working fine when I refresh browser. Please let me know what should I do to solve this kinda issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using MetaMask. MetaMask hides wallet addresses by default to preserve privacy. If you're using MM, you should use `@web3-react/metamask`.